# How to know form data changed while saving the form in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I Created one app to register employee.There are multiple forms to fill and save data in database, every form(page) have cancel and save buttons.Here i wanted to give alert like "you will lose your changes" when user edited the form and click on cancel button. Using servlet and jsp i can know form changes.But I don't know in Android. Is it possible in Android. Please help me any one..

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we did in our Flex application to solve this problem, was to keep a global variable in the page and added a listener to whenever any thing in the form was changed. In that case the variable is set to true.

Then when Cancel is clicked, if the value is true, we show a popup saying there are unsaved changes. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Thanks Silverback, But all my 34 forms contains morethan 50 components like check boxes,spinners and radios. should i write listeners to all my components. Is there any way other than this.

Comment: I guess not all,you can try to insert listeners like onItemListener for buttons, onItemSelectedListener for spinners etc, when it comes inside these listeners it has clicked on something, so you can say user has edited something, so set a global boolean variable true in this listener, continue like this. So at the end, the number of different types of widgets you have(Buttons, Spinners etc) that many listeners you will. Eg. 5 spinners will have a common onItemSelectedListener, 7 checkboxes will have a common onCheckedChangedListener.

Comment: Everything fine but, how to deal with Date pickers in the form.I have to check when the date was changed in the field,not when click on the date icon.Some of my forms contains more than 10 date picker icons.

Comment: Sometimes changes are occurred, but user may decide to undo changes. if we set the variable to true in all mentioned listeners, we have wrong value to detect if any changes occurred or not. The variable said change is occurred but in reality we know no changes occurred. do you have idea how we can deal with this issue? @VedangJadhav

Comment: we need to keep a variable for initial value, and compare it with the current value to decide if the field has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think in android you will have to write your own custom validation that is run when the user clicks on the cancel button.

Comment: Thank you Roy James Schumacher, In Custom Validation how to check the changes in the form.My form contains more than 50 components.

Comment: probably the most efficient way to do it with that many components is to use silverbacks solution and add listeners to everything